# Problems opening Excel attachments from Outlook

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook

I'm seeing issues with Excel attachments in Outlook 2013; Trying to preview in Outlook gives error:

> The file cannot be previewed because of an error with the following previewer:
>
> Microsoft Excel previewer
>
> To open this file in its own program, double-click it.

And when following that advice, I get error:

> Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.
>
> - To make more memory available, close workbooks or programs you no longer need.
> - To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk you are saving to.

Task manager reports 4.9Gb free RAM (although its only the x86 version of Office); Explorer reports 55.5Gb free disk space; Perfmon reports Excel as only using 45Mb (private bytes), and the Excel file (generated by Reporting Services 2008) is only 56Kb, with , so I have reason to believe the error message is erroneous.

I've already tried a "repair" of Office, with no effect, and have also confirmed the program associations at **Control Panel** \ **All Control Panel Items** \ **Default Programs** \ **Set Default Programs** \ **Set Program Associations**

What might be causing this, and short of a complete rebuild of the PC, is there anything I've missed that I can try to fix the issue with?

**EDIT:** Doing some further diagnosis, I've taken a "working" Excel document, emailed it to myself, and saved it into the same folder (with a subtly different name). The two files are binary identical, however the one that has been through Outlook is "Blocked" - unblocking it through the properties page makes it work.

Now, this makes me suspect that "some security setting" has been changed, but where would I change this setting (that I don't know what it might be called)?

Comment: Maybe the atachment is corrupted? Are you able to save the attachment and open it outside of outlook?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you save the attachment first and then try to open it?

Comment: I'm unable to preview any Excel attachments, but saving them to disk and opening from there usually allows me to open attachments that I can't normally open. I'm suspicious that some COM component has had it's registration go a bit squiffy, which is why I tried the repair...

Comment: The error message "not enough memory" is some kind of generic error message used by excel when, for real have no memory left, or you have permisson issues. Try to start excel as admin and try to open the attachment again. I would guess that excel needs to store the attatchment in some temporary folder before it opens it and because there are some permission issues he cant save that file there before opening it. If you can find out where he tries to store the file you could change the folder permission so that you dont have to start outlook with admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, go to File/Options/Trust Center/Trust Center Settings/Protected View.  Untick the "Enable Protected View for Outlook Attachments" - and all will be well.

Bear in mind, of course, that this option defaults to the safer "make the user conciously decide that they really want to open the workbook" - so make sure you trust the source of any Excel files you're receiving.

Comment: Whilst this doesn't resolve the previewer, I can at least double click the attachments and open them now :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is usually because the Windows Firewall service is not started.  Protected View requires an active Windows Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when Excel can not locate system's Temporary folder and can be fixed by doing the following:

Open, Start → Run → regedit → Go to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

and modify the key Cache with a valid path (i.e.: `C:\Windows\Temp` ).

Alternatively you can use this registry file to do it automatically (Right-Click → Save as).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is usually because the Windows firewall is not started. Outlook 2013 and up uses the Windows firewall for the trust Center.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is **not** that the workbook would not open but that the error message is both incorrect and misleading.

Now perhaps a third party application will not know the true reason for not being able to open a file (though I suspect that third parties exercise greater care and diligence), but Excel and Windows are both produced by the same house. One would expect the developers then to talk to each other and that their applications would also do so.

Assuming that the operating system and the application itself are both up to date and uncorrupted, there are several causes behind a failure to open a file, inter alia:

1 a lack of system resource be it memory, disk space, handles etc.

2 a corruption in the file which the application has not been designed to handle

3 permissions on the file

In the case above it is the permissions on the file. The file is blocked. Remove the block and the file opens.

It is beyond my comprehension that an MS application running on an MS system cannot distinguish between the three possible causes I have mentioned above. Who has failed? Is it is the Excel programmer who, knowing that the OS will provide at least a flag identifying the problem, has failed to implement this in the error messages? Or is it the developer of the OS who has failed to provide the correct identifier to the application? Either way, this is not a system issue at all, it is a [lazy] people issue.

The error message is not even as useful as 'Have you turned it off and on again?' If the error message, in this case, were true then it would be quite likely that the file would open after the resumption of service.

Concerning the blocking of the file by Outlook when it is downloaded, none of the suggested solutions (eg going to the Security/Trust centre to make 'appropriate' changes, or checking the Windows Firewall settings) appear to make any difference. If there is a way to prevent the blocking of files I shall be glad to learn of it. The Windows help (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/performance/cannot-open-word-documents-or-excel-spreadsheets) for this message is particularly unhelpful, as it seems to suggest that the [only] cause of the problem is a disabled Windows Firewall.

Now, I am not suggesting that the other 'solutions' offered above are not worth considering, but they should not be offered as solutions to the problem presented to us. They are merely matters to be investigated. Roland Shaw indicates that he has already examined the matter carefully. We need to step back a little, to see the real problem, which as I said is the error message itself. The problem is nothing to do with memory, or firewall, or trust centre settings. Note that if the trust centre settings are 'incorrect' there is a different information message.

Thank you.