# Office 2013 on Windows 8.1 gives out of memory error when opening files

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8.1, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

We have the same error that has been posted here:

[Problems opening Excel attachments from Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/867923/problems-opening-excel-attachments-from-outlook)

Namely, when a user opens a file from the internet, the internal network or an outlook attachment the office program will launch and gave an Out of Memory Error message. Yet if that same file is moved to the local computer and opened the file opens without a problem.

I have gotten around this by disabling protected view for files from the internet, outlook attachments and potentially unsafe locations. The problem with this fix is that the user cannot preview these files anymore because the protected view is now disabled and this is potentially very unsafe in my opinion as this disables a good feature in office.

Is there anyway to fix this problem so that protected view will still function?

I am seeing this error on 4 different computers, all of which are Windows 8.1 pro and are running office 2013 pro plus.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems opening Excel attachments from Outlook](http://superuser.com/questions/867923/problems-opening-excel-attachments-from-outlook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have moved on from this issue, if users have this problem we quickly disable the protected view options, but this seems to be resolved or at least the problem alleviated through a Windows update for Office 2013, or in our case using Office 2016.